# NullPointerException running DataNucleus Enhancer 3.1.0-release

Tags: java, dos, jdo, datanucleus

I am running DataNucleus enhancer from DOS as follows:

```
java -cp C:\Users\Chania\workspace\myproject\war\WEB-INF\classes\;C:\repo\datanucleus-full-3.1.0-release\lib\datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.0-release.jar;C:\repo\datanucleus-full-3.1.0-release\lib\datanucleus-core-3.1.0-release.jar;C:\repo\datanucleus-full-3.1.0-release\deps\jdo-api-3.1-SNAPSHOT-20110926.jar;C:\repo\datanucleus-full-3.1.0-release\lib\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.0-release.jar;C:\repo\datanucleus-full-3.1.0-release\deps\log4j-1.2.14.jar;C:\repo\datanucleus-full-3.1.0-release\deps\asm-4.0.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:\repo\datanucleus-full-3.1.0-release\log4j.properties org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer -v C:\Users\Chania\workspace\myproject\war\WEB-INF\classes\com\myproject\domain\*.class > logfile.txt
```

The Java version that I'm using is:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
```

The error that I'm getting is as follows:

```
 ...
 308  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Added converter for java.net.URI<->java.lang.String using org.datanucleus.store.types.converters.URIStringConverter
 308  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Added converter for java.net.URL<->java.lang.String using org.datanucleus.store.types.converters.URLStringConverter
 309  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Added converter for java.util.UUID<->java.lang.String using org.datanucleus.store.types.converters.UUIDStringConverter
 309  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - TypeConverter for javax.time.calendar.LocalDate<->java.lang.String ignored since java type not present in CLASSPATH
 310  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - TypeConverter for javax.time.calendar.LocalTime<->java.lang.String ignored since java type not present in CLASSPATH
 311  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - TypeConverter for javax.time.calendar.LocalTime<->java.lang.Long ignored since java type not present in CLASSPATH
 312  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - TypeConverter for javax.time.calendar.LocalDateTime<->java.lang.String ignored since java type not present in CLASSPATH
 312  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Type converter support loaded
 312  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.MetaData  - MetaDataManager : Input=(XML,Annotations), XML-Validation=false, XML-Suffices=(persistence=*.jdo, orm=orm, query=*.jdoquery), JDO-listener=false
 338  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.MetaData  - MetaData Management : Loading Metadata for classes "[com.myproject.domain.Record, com.myproject.domain.RecordSummary, com.myproject.domain.Comment]" ...
 411  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.MetaData  - Class "com.myproject.domain.Record" has been specified with JDO annotations so using those.
 596  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.MetaData  - Class "com.myproject.domain.RecordSummary" has been specified with JDO annotations so using those.
 600  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.MetaData  - Class "com.myproject.domain.Comment" has been specified with JDO annotations so using those.
 Errors were encountered when loading the specified MetaData files and classes. See the nested exceptions for details
604  [main] ERROR DataNucleus.Enhancer  - DataNucleus Enhancer completed with an error. Please review the enhancer log for full details. Some classes may have been enhanced but some caused errors
 Errors were encountered when loading the specified MetaData files and classes. See the nested exceptions for details
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when loading the specified MetaData files and classes. See the nested exceptions for details
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:536)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:734)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOAnnotationReader.processMemberAnnotations(JDOAnnotationReader.java:1682)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getMetaDataForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:206)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManager.java:2650)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:496)
    ... 3 more
Nested Throwables StackTrace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOAnnotationReader.processMemberAnnotations(JDOAnnotationReader.java:1682)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getMetaDataForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:206)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManager.java:2650)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:496)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:734)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with an error. Please review the enhancer log for full details. Some classes may have been enhanced but some caused errors
```

The sources for the enhanced classes are as follows:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Record implements Serializable, Cacheable<String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9022509306966814904L;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Name
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String name;

    @Name
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String surname;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Date dateRecorded;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String locationId;

    @Persistent(embedded = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private CustomLocation customLocation;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Category category;

    @Persistent(embedded = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private CustomCategory customCategory;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String description;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private List<StoredImageInfo> images;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private List<StoredAudioInfo> audio;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private List<StoredFileInfo> files;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private ModerationMode moderationMode;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private VisibilityMode visibilityMode;

    @Persistent(embedded = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private UserProfileSummary owner;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Map<String, UserProfileSummary> editors;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Map<String, UserProfileSummary> connections;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Map<String, RecordSummary> recordConnections;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private RecordType type;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Date expiry;

    public Record() {
    }

    public Record(Record copy) {
        deepCopy(copy);
    }

    ...
}


@PersistenceCapable(embeddedOnly = "true")
public class RecordSummary implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9024309306966814904L;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String id;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private RecordRole role;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String name;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String surname;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Date dateRecorded;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private RecordSummary() {
        // for serialization
    }

    ...
}


@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Comment implements Attachable<String>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7624377549524333808L;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String recordId;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String username;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Date date;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String content;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Comment() {
        // for serialization
    }

    ...
}
```

I am not getting any such Exceptions with datanucleus enhancer 3.0-release (albeit, having other problems with 3.0: [problem 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842527/nullpointerexception-in-jdopersistencemanager-getobjectbyid-using-datanucleus), [problem 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846170/flaky-loading-of-1-n-relationships-with-datanucleus-3-0-0-release)).  **Is this a bug with DataNucleus 3.1 or am I doing something wrong?**

**UPDATE**: DataNucleus Enhancer throws a `NullPointerException` for all List fields marked with `@Persistent(embeddedElement = "true")`.  It is highly likely that this is a bug with the DataNucleus 3.1 Enhancer.

**UPDATE 2**: Upon request, I am including minimal code that reproduces the problem:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Record {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private List<MyEmbeddedElement> aList;

    public Record() {
    }

}


@PersistenceCapable(embeddedOnly = "true")
public class MyEmbeddedElement {

    @Persistent
    private String myField;

}
```

The error:

```
 730  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.MetaData  - Class "com.myproject.domain.Record" has been specified with JDO annotations so using those.
 760  [main] DEBUG DataNucleus.MetaData  - Class "com.myproject.domain.MyEmbeddedElement" has been specified with JDO annotations so using those.
 Errors were encountered when loading the specified MetaData files and classes. See the nested exceptions for details
763  [main] ERROR DataNucleus.Enhancer  - DataNucleus Enhancer completed with an error. Please review the enhancer log for full details. Some classes may have been enhanced but some caused errors
 Errors were encountered when loading the specified MetaData files and classes. See the nested exceptions for details
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when loading the specified MetaData files and classes. See the nested exceptions for details
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:536)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:734)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOAnnotationReader.processMemberAnnotations(JDOAnnotationReader.java:1682)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getMetaDataForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:206)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManager.java:2650)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:496)
    ... 3 more
Nested Throwables StackTrace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOAnnotationReader.processMemberAnnotations(JDOAnnotationReader.java:1682)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getMetaDataForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:206)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManager.java:2650)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:496)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:734)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with an error. Please review the enhancer log for full details. Some classes may have been enhanced but some caused errors
```

**UPDATE 3**: This problem exists in all DataNucleus releases starting with 3.0.2.

Comment: I have no problems using v3.1 and use embedded relations all over the place in my app. Perhaps you ought to cut your classes down to something minimal with just some field causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do an embedded collection in my app I do

```
@Element(embedded="true")
Collection<OtherType> myCollField;
```

and that works for me, and looks more logical way of specifying embedded elements.

Also your map fields are wrong ... a map has no "element", it has "key" and "value"

Comment: Using `@Element(embedded="true")` results in the enhancer giving a `"Field "com.MyClass.[collectionField]" is a collection with elements of type "java.util.Collection" yet has been specified as the element being embedded. Your embedded type must be PersistenceCapable"` error (even when the embedded type is a `String`)

Actually, I started off using `embeddedKey` and `embeddedValue` for maps with DataNucleus 3.0, but that failed (can't remember the error), whereas using `embeddedElement` for the `Map`s worked.

Comment: I have done some more testing of this and the `Map`s are working fine, but its the enhancer's handling of `embeddedElement` placed on a field of type `List` that is causing the `NullPointerException`

Comment: Obviously "OtherType" has to be PersistenceCapable ... since you're saying embed it. My embedded classes are persistable and so I get no exception. As already said a map has no element, so that metadata is just wrong ... so maybe DataNucleus ignores your incorrect metadata on those.

Comment: The other type **is** PersistenceCapable; note that I have written that the result is same even if a List of Strings is used.  Same with Maps: using embeddedElement may be wrong in terms of JDO, but DataNucleus fails when embeddedValue is used for a Map and works with embeddedElement, which is why I am using embeddedElement.

Comment: As already said, all of mine work, and since I can see all of my code then I'm confident in what I say. OTOH I cannot see a simple *complete* example of yours ... you quote one class with dozens of relations, and don't quote the related class, hence incomplete

Comment: I've included a minimal class that reproduces the same problem.  See "UPDATE 2" section.

Comment: You have List<String> and that is nothing to do with "embeddedElement". "embeddedElement" is for use when the field is a collection of PersistenceCapable objects, as already said.

Comment: Neil, you are very hard to please :))   I have updated the code and error message in the "UPDATE 2" section.

Comment: When I said use @Element(embedded="true") why don't you use that?

Comment: Interesting; I have tested again and @Element(embedded="true") does work for my Lists.  I must have botched something when tried it last night.  _So, for the record: DataNucleus Enhancer 3.1 does not throw a `NullPointerException` when `@Element(embedded="true")` is used instead of `@Persistent(embeddedElement="true")`._