# NullPointerException in JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById() using DataNucleus 3.0.0-release

Tags: java, mongodb, jdo, datanucleus

I am using DataNucleus 3.0.0-release JDO implementation to connect my Java app to MongoDB.

The related JARs in my CLASSPATH are as follows:

- datanucleus-api-jdo-3.0.0-release.jar
- datanucleus-core-3.0.0-release.jar
- datanucleus-jdo-query-3.0.0-release.jar
- datanucleus-mongodb-3.0.0-release.jar
- mongo-java-driver-2.5.2.jar

The class that I am persisting is as follows:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Record implements Serializable, Cacheable<String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9022509306966814904L;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Name
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String name;

    @Name
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String surname;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Date dateRecorded;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String locationId;

    @Persistent(embedded = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private CustomLocation customLocation;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Category category;

    @Persistent(embedded = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private CustomCategory customCategory;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String description;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private List<StoredImageInfo> images;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private List<StoredAudioInfo> audio;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private List<StoredFileInfo> files;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private ModerationMode moderationMode;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private VisibilityMode visibilityMode;

    @Persistent(embedded = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private UserProfileSummary owner;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Map<String, UserProfileSummary> editors;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Map<String, UserProfileSummary> connections;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Map<String, RecordSummary> recordConnections;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private RecordType type;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Date expiry;

    public Record() {
    }

    public Record(Record copy) {
    deepCopy(copy);
    }

    ...
}
```

And the `CustomLocation` class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(embeddedOnly="true")
public class CustomLocation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7754029273366194129L;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String city;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String countryKey;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String locale;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private CustomLocation() {
        // for serialization
    }
    ...
}
```

The code that tries to fetch the object from the DB is as follows:

```
PersistenceManager pm = MyPersistenceManagerFactory.get().getPersistenceManager();

Record record = null;
try {
    record = pm.getObjectById(Record.class, recordId);
}
catch (JDOObjectNotFoundException onfe) {
    // handle
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // handle
}
```

The following is the resulting error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.fieldmanager.FetchFieldManager.fetchStringField(FetchFieldManager.java:243)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingStringField(AbstractStateManager.java:2165)
    at com.myproject.location.domain.CustomLocation.jdoReplaceField(CustomLocation.java)
    at com.myproject.location.domain.CustomLocation.jdoReplaceFields(CustomLocation.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.replaceFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1989)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.replaceFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2009)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.fieldmanager.FetchFieldManager.fetchObjectField(FetchFieldManager.java:353)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2182)
    at com.myproject.domain.Record.jdoReplaceField(Record.java)
    at com.myproject.domain.Record.jdoReplaceFields(Record.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.replaceFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1989)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.replaceFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2009)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.MongoDBPersistenceHandler.fetchObject(MongoDBPersistenceHandler.java:600)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadFieldsFromDatastore(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1696)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.validate(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3576)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3246)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1731)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1749)
    at com.myproject.server.GetRecordHandler.execute(GetRecordHandler.java:37)
```

Can anyone spot what the problem is?

*Note: I know that DataNucleus 3.1.0-release is available, but I can't use it because of a [problem with its enhancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823840/nullpointerexception-running-datanucleus-enhancer-3-1-0-release).*

**UPDATE:** I have done some further testing of this issue and it turns out that DataNucleus throws a `NullPointerException` for those `embedded` fields that are also marked as being in the `defaultFetchGroup` and have a value of `null`.

Comment: Why would you use some really old version when there is v3.0.10 long after that, never mind many 3.1.0 releases? I'm using 3.1.0 but used various 3.0.x releases and have had no problems, so suggest you debug your problem to what is causing you the problem

Comment: 3.0.10 is not an official release and DataNucleus advises only to use official release versions (those that end with "-release") in production systems.

Comment: Incorrect. I see nothing on the DataNucleus site that says that.