# Flaky Loading of 1-N Relationships with DataNucleus 3.x

Tags: java, mongodb, jdo, datanucleus

I am using DataNucleus 3.0.0-release JDO implementation to connect my Java app to MongoDB.

The related JARs in my CLASSPATH are as follows:

- datanucleus-api-jdo-3.0.0-release.jar
- datanucleus-core-3.0.0-release.jar
- datanucleus-jdo-query-3.0.0-release.jar
- datanucleus-mongodb-3.0.0-release.jar
- mongo-java-driver-2.5.2.jar

**UPDATE**:  This problem also occurred with version 3.1 and is related to DataNucleus' Level2 cache.  See my answer below for a workaround.

The class that I am trying to load is as follows:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable, Cacheable<String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7132595253084641884L;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String username;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String name;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String surname;

    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private Map<String, UserProfileSummary> connections;

    ...
}
```

The following is the UserProfileSummary class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(embeddedOnly = "true")
public class UserProfileSummary implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6120670018375572406L;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String username;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private String fullName;
    ...
}
```

The following is how I am trying to load stored objects of type `UserProfile`:

```
PersistenceManager pm = MyPersistenceManagerFactory.get().getPersistenceManager();

UserProfile profile = null;
try {
    profile = pm.getObjectById(UserProfile.class, username);
}
catch (JDOObjectNotFoundException onfe) {
    // handle
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // handle
}
```

The problem is that the `connections` field of `UserProfile` is sometimes loaded correctly, but sometimes loaded as `null` with the same call to `getObjectById()`.  The field is marked to be in the `defaultFetchGroup`, so it should be loaded every time.

**Could this be a DataNucleus bug (race condition?)?  Is anyone else experiencing the same problem?**

*Note: I know that DataNucleus 3.1.0-release is available, but I can't use it because of a [problem with its enhancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823840/nullpointerexception-running-datanucleus-enhancer-3-1-0-release).*

Comment: I'm sure looking at the log would tell you plenty about what is happening. I'm equally sure that using a release from exactly a year ago, when there have been 15+ releases since is not what I would call "best practice".

Comment: I was told that the only releases that are ready for production use are those named "...-release".  Are you saying that this is not the case?

Comment: Total nonsense, and whoever told you that ought to be ashamed (it was nobody involved in this project). The DataNucleus docs define versioning and *every* release is "production ready".

Comment: [This problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823840/nullpointerexception-running-datanucleus-enhancer-3-1-0-release) occurs in all DataNucleus releases starting with 3.0.2, which limits me to 3.0.1.  I'll see if that release fixes the 1-N issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have turned DataNucleus level2 cache off and from preliminary tests it seems like this problem has disappeared.

To turn the level2 cache off, add the following line to your jdoconfig.xml:

```
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java. ... .xsd">
    <persistence-manager-factory name="MyPMF">
        ...
        <property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="none" />
    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

Comment: Obviously unilaterally declaring something is a problem in feature XXX of version YYY on a third party site without defining a test that demonstrates it is of little use to anyone else, and of no use to that software. The responsible thing to do is provide a valid testcase against latest release, raise JIRA issue, attach testcase etc. As per http://www.datanucleus.org/project/problem_reporting.html

Comment: Hi Neil, when I find the time, I will try to set up a minimal, standalone Java app that loads an object with a 1-N relationship, closes the pm, and then tries to load it again.  Hopefully, that will reproduce this problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it, but who's Neil?